# Ruby: encrypt directories (folders)

Tags: ruby, filesystems, directory

is there a way, to encrypt directories, using ruby.

To get in detail:

I would like to create a directory, that You can only access, by entering a password.

Comment: This is usually done by creating an encrypted "disk" (which is just a file) and mounting it as a filesystem using a custom FS driver. This is a lot of work, by the way.

Comment: Oh thanks. I am gonna read some stuff about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One example is [FileVault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileVault) which is bundled with OS X. A similar thing could be done on other platforms using the same approach, an encrypted disk image and a [loop-back device](http://www.walkernews.net/2007/07/01/create-linux-loopback-file-system-on-disk-file/).

Another option is to leverage [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) which allows you to create a filesystem in userspace and in presumably any language that can answer the calls made by the kernel.

I would be very cautious when doing this, though. The point of encryption is to keep things hidden, and if you're spraying unencrypted versions of this filesystem all over system memory you're defeating the purpose. Most "secure" filesystems like FileVault do a lot more than encrypt your files.